# How to clear node.js terminal in Cent OS 7

Tags: node.js, terminal, centos7

I'm using Node.js in VScode. Say my run command is node index.js.  As I run command various console.log statements print during course now I want to clear console log without stopping current node process. In existing case To clear the console I have to stop the running process using Ctrl+c. use clear command in terminal to clear screen and again run the process using node index.js. My question is there any method by using which i can clear terminal window without stopping current node process.

Comment: You need to restart the Node process anyway before your changes take effect.

Comment: What if I want to clear various log statement of running console without restarting node process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.clear()` function in your node program. If you want to clear vscode terminal window, just click by right mouse on terminal and select `Clear` (shortcut `Ctrl + K`)

Comment: Question still remains. Need information of command or shorcut for running linux terminal witout stoping a running node instance. Besides using console.clear() in node program clears console during execution at certain point and my question was to clear terminal at any time as per my disposal.